# How to access a HTML attribute within a string? vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, string, attributes

How do I access the HTML attributes within this string?

```
'This champion has <ability value=43>Immunity: Disease</ability>.  While you control at least 5 Zombies, this unit gains <ability value=2147>Swarm: Festering Corpse</ability>.'
```

I want to get the data from the value attribute within the ability tags. Is this possible with Javascript

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the text as HTML using `document.createElement`:

```js
var text = "This champion has <ability value=43>Immunity: Disease</ability>.  While you control at least 5 Zombies, this unit gains <ability value=2147>Swarm: Festering Corpse</ability>.";
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.innerHTML = text;
var elems = newNode.children;
var i = 0;
while(i < elems.length) {
  console.log(elems[i].innerText, elems[i].getAttribute("value"));
  i++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result by converting your string to html and then read abilities from produced html, like this:

```js
const str = 'This champion has <ability value=43>Immunity: Disease</ability>.  While you control at least 5 Zombies, this unit gains <ability value=2147>Swarm: Festering Corpse</ability>.'
const abilities = [];
const tempEl = document.createElement('div');
tempEl.innerHTML = str;

const abilityTags = tempEl.querySelectorAll('ability');
abilityTags.forEach((ability) => {
  abilities.push(ability.getAttribute('value') /*or whatever you want read from ability tag*/ )
});
console.log(abilities)
```